# Trying to find some really old versions of software

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, java, flash, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I am currently trying to track down some old versions of Adobe Flash, Adobe Acrobat 9, Adobe Reader XI and Java Runtime Environment so that a Windows 2012R2 server can run a piece of [redacted] application that the client must have. I have had a look for these installers but I am unable to see anything offered. The closest I got was for Adobe Reader XI, I found an upgrade file to 11.0.07, but I think I would need a full installer.

List of version needed is:

Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX: 10.0.22.87

Adobe Acrobat 9: 9.0.0

Adobe Reader XI: 11.0.07

Java Runtime Environment: 1.5.0.110

Does anyone have any advice on which tree to bark up?

Answer (score 2):

I googled for "old versions of [software]" and got:

- [Adobe Flash](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)
- [Adobe Reader](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/)
- [Acrobat](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/)
- [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html)

There are also web sites that claim to have old versions, but they look hinky to me. These are all vendor links.

[Edit:  I feel your pain.  I used to support some horrible nursing videos that required QuickTime 2--no lie.]

Comment: You must be Santa because this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your help, I was being too specific in my search it seems.

It is a horrible situation isn't it

Comment: Yeah, it stinks.  You're welcome!